# Preserve special characters when parsing variables from http request to c# string

Tags: c#, http, request, owin

I am working on a small application based on owin and katana to handle links internally.
So the application handles HttpGet requests. When someone calls

> http:localhost/?document=path/to/my/document/foo.doc

the application opens this document.

My problem is: When the document name contains a special character like '+' my code interprets the + sign as space because the variable is parsed into a string.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string document = "")
    {
        //open document
    }
```

So how to preserve the special characters and don't allow c# string to convert them before executing any code?

I tried with `HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri]string document = "")`

I tried encoding the document variable afterwards with HttpUtility.UrlEncode but it will also encode the legit spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I got a workaround:
    this.Request.RequestUri.OriginalString
inside of the GET Method will give the the full link as string without any interpretations. The rest is to get the relevant variable with string.substring operations.

Nevertheless it would like to know if someone knows a more elegant solution.